# What can I set in rigid body and collidable objects to ensure that the angle after collision is larger?

Tags: physics, physics-engine, physx

I have a rigid body with sphere shape attached and a static collidable box. When sphere hits the box at an angle, for some reason, the angle that it bounces off from is really small: https://imgpile.com/i/59FC34

I want to increase this angle somehow. What properties can I change in a rigid body to control this angle? NVIDIA PhysX allows changing interia, center of mass, mass, linear and angular dampening, restitution and friction (shape).

Comment: When you say "increase", which direction do you mean? Toward the surface or toward the normal? Try drawing a diagram showing your current angle of incidence and angle of reflection, and overlay it with the angle of reflection you'd prefer for the same incident angle.

Comment: Something like this? https://imgpile.com/i/5CgvTR

Comment: That looks like a symptom of friction being too great, so your ball loses some lateral speed by rubbing against the wall.. Though it's not obvious to me in your video that you're actually getting an angle as biased toward the normal as what's shown in the diagram. To my eye, it looks much closer to the expected angle of incidence = angle of reflection, it's just that the angle of incidence is quite steep so the reflection is steep to match.

Comment: Thank you i'll check it out and see if I can figure this out. I just wanted to use the physics system to simulate collision for a pong game but looks like I am going to need additional logic to fake some of the forces that come from the collision.

Comment: I set the friction to ZERO and that solved the issue. Thank you!

Comment: Be sure to post your solution as an Answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After @DMGregory's suggestion, I started to play around with the friction. All the objects had both static and dynamic friction set to 1.0. So, I just set them to 0.0 to ensure that no energy was lost due to friction, which solved my problem. In order to improve collision even further, I also applied a bit of torque to the ball to make it roll.